# Manipulation of XML Attribute datetime

Tags: c#, xml, http, soap

I can serialize XML string. But I can't create XML attribute for datetime like this

```
<StartDate xsi:type=xsd:dateTime>datevalue</StartDate>
```

I am using the c# class to represent the XML elements.

I can't produce the xsi:type attribute.

I want to create it programmatically, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public DateRange()
{
    type = "xsd:dateTime";
}

[XmlAttribute(Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance", AttributeName = "type")]
public string type { get; set; }
```